# How can I see compiler's output when running task in Visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

Everytime I try to run the build task, I can't see anything except from `The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1`, how can I configure VSCode so I can see compiler's output?

Below is my task file and what I've got from running build task:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW32/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "mysockets.cpp"
            ],
            "presentation": {
                "echo": true,
                "reveal": "always",
                "focus": false,
                "panel": "shared",
                "showReuseMessage": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": "$gcc",
        },
    ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: If you manually run exactly that command on the command line, what is the output?

Comment: "cannot recognize (x86) as cmdlet, functions, shell scripts or executable", if I wrap compiler path with quotes, then it will say "unexpected -g in the expression".

Comment: Not sure it matters, but make sure you are using the correct path separator: \ instead of /